# How to know if npm installation is correct?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node.js v16.14.0 in Windows 10. Now I want to install npm, currently I have the following directories:

- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm - which contains files and folders (are they installed with node.js?)
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm - which is empty (should it be empty?)

Now I am going to install npm. When I open the command prompt and type `npm install` I get the following error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'`

So, I type `cd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` and then `npm install`.
The console output says `added 335 packages, changed 16 packages, and audited 710 packages in 50s` but the path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm is still empty.

So,

1. Have I installed correctly npm?
2. Did I install it just when I install node.js?
3. What did the npm install did?

Edit:
I try typing the command `npm install npm -g` and now the folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm is not empty anymore

Comment: Be sure you're running npm install inside of your sourcecode folder.  looks like your current working directory when running is c:\windows\system32.

Comment: @MichaelG It was C:\Users\user\ I added another step I just made

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but npm should be installed when Node is installed and doesn't require a separate installation. The fact that you can run `npm install` shows that npm is installed correctly.